# Formatting trader_sma decimals

Tags: php, format, precision

This code

```
$real = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 9 ) ;
$timePeriod = 5;
$data = trader_sma($real,$timePeriod);
$ta_sma = $data[4];
echo $ta_sma;
```

Gives nice result of "3.8"

But this one

```
$real = array (0.00035606, 0.00035571, 0.00035607, 0.00035606, 5.00035607);
$timePeriod = 5;
$data = trader_sma($real,$timePeriod);
$ta_sma = $data[4];
echo $ta_sma;
```

is giving "1" (no decimal numbers)

I tried all possible number_format combinations and could not get normal result in 2nd code

How to format this to get real number which is 1,000355994?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking here - [php trader configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/trader.configuration.php) we can figure out two options:

1. Set an `trader.real_precision` option in php.ini to `9`, which means the precision of rounding (amount of numbers after the dot)
2. Set it directly in the script:

   ini_set('trader.real_precision', '9');

And we have in output:

```
array(1) {
      [4]=>
      float(1.000355994)
  }
```

Comment: THANK YOU @EugeneR